# Best place (and time) to insert ACLs/ACEs in n-tiers architecture

Tags: php, security, acl, n-tier-architecture, event-driven-design

With all the processes we need to separate in a scalable web architecture and specifically in an Event Driven Design (synchronous and asynchonous jobs), i wonder where is the best place (and also the best time) to insert ACEs.

My first "naïve" move would be to insert them in the same service method the related object is created  in.

It would be something like :

```
class AlbumManager
{
    public function createAlbum(Album $album)
    {        
        $this->albumRepository->save($album);

        $this->permissionManager->grantPrivileges($album->getUser(), $album, MaskBuilder::MASK_OWNER);

        $event = new AlbumEvent($album);
        $this->dispatcher->dispatch(AlbumEvents::CREATE, $event);
    }
}
```

But, is that the right place ? Since other stuffs are handled in Event Listeners which delegate works synchronously or asynchronously (offline queue), why don't do the same with ACEs ?

Typically, in the application, you always identify the operations that need to be done immediatly, and the ones that can (must) be done offline (queue).

Where the security stuff lies in there ? ;-)

Thanks,
Bye.

Benjamin.